# Running Ada on the Zynq using a Digilent Zybo development board

Tags: ada, xilinx, zynq, gnat-gps

I've been successfully using Vivado and the SDK to develop VHDL and C for the `Zynq XC7Z010` on a Digilent Zybo board. I've also been using the GNAT GPS IDE to learn Ada targeted to an `STM32F4` processor (using one of the supported development boards).

GPS also ships with a set of `zynq7000` run-times targeted to the `XC7Z020` (as far as I can tell). Having looked through the BSPs for these target I believe that the code generated should also run on the `XC7Z010` as the ARM cores appear to be the same. It may turn out that there are differences, in which case I will have a go at building a specific run-time based on the existing `zynq7000` BSP (Adacore have documented this process and give an example for generating a new `STM32F4` BSP).

My main problem is I'm not sure how to load and run the generated Ada `elf` file on my Zybo. I have tried to generate a `BOOT.ini` file containing a `FSBL` (built with the SDK and using my exported hardware from Vivado), a bit-stream and the Ada `elf` file (The the Zybo has an MicroSD interface that can be configured as a boot device, this works perfectly with a bit-stream and C `elf` produced via Vivado / SDK).

Anyway, this didn't work... I'm guessing that it might be a linking issue, or a boot loader issue, or similar. With my current level of knowledge I'm just not sure at this stage.

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that my `BOOT.ini` was fine, the problem was related to accessing custom `AXI` registers defined in my bit-stream. If I remove these references from the Ada the generated `ELF` file works perfectly. For example, printing over the Zybo's VCP using `Text_IO.Put_Line()`, using Ada run-time `delay` and `Clock` operations etc.

For some reason the `AXI` interface isn't working when I boot an Ada `ELF` file. If I substitute this for the equivalent C, then all is well.

This particular problem is currently unresolved, but not related to my original question!

(It might be that the Ada run-time is relying on the `FSBL` or `u-Boot` to have initialised this, not sure. Feel free to comment if you know, I'll also add a comment when I resolve this)

**** Update ****

Here is some additional background and a description of what I had to do to get my custom AXI IPs to work.

The provided AdaCore `BSP` (Board Support Package used to build the run-time) is targeted at the Xilinx `XC702` development board. I'm using a Digilent Zybo (the older version). The two boards use different Zynq parts, the `XC702` is based on a `XC7Z020` and the Zybo uses a `XC7Z010` (there is a new version with a `XC7Z020` option).

I followed the AdaCore instructions (available on their web site) and built a `BSP` specifically for the Zybo. Initially I just updated the clock details as the Zybo runs at a different speed and then verified that the Ada `delay` function worked correctly (provided as part of the `Ravenscar` run-time built from the updated `BSP`). However, my custom `AXI` IPs still didn't work...

To cut a long story short, the Ada run-time contains as assembly file called `start-ram.S` that amongst other things sets up the `MMU`. There is an include file called `memmap.inc` that contains the actual `MMU` page definitions as a series of `.long` directives. I had to update the `AXI_GP0` address entry by editing the particular directive to,

```
.long 0x43c10c16  @ for 0x43c00000, axi_gp0
```

Previously it was set to `0x00000000 @ for 0x43c00000, *none*`. These entries are decoded within `start-ram.S` and then used to configure the `MMU` (the top 12 bits set the page and the remaining bits are chopped up and used as page config).

So, once I edited this file in my Zybo `BSP` and re-built the run-time, the IPs became accessible from the PS and worked as expected. This all took a while to figure out, but was worth it as I learn loads whilst exploring the dead ends!

I hope this helps someone in the future, I also highly recommend Ada for Zynq development especially if you ultimately need DO-178 certification, or similar.